# Java Performance Processes vs Threads

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, process, worker

I am implementing a worker pool in Java.

This is essentially a whole load of objects which will pick up chunks of data, process the data and then store the result. Because of IO latency there will be significantly more workers than processor cores.

The server is dedicated to this task and I want to wring the maximum performance out of the hardware (but no I don't want to implement it in C++).

The simplest implementation would be to have a single Java process which creates and monitors a number of worker threads. An alternative would be to run a Java process for each worker.

Assuming for arguments sake a quadcore Linux server which of these solutions would you anticipate being more performant and why?

You can assume the workers never need to communicate with one another.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

One process, multiple threads - for a few reasons.

When context-switching between jobs, it's cheaper on some processors to switch between threads than between processes.  This is especially important in this kind of I/O-bound case with more workers than cores.  The more work you do between getting I/O blocked, the less important this is.  Good buffering will pay for threads *or* processes, though.

When switching between threads in the same JVM, at least some Linux implementations (x86, in particular) don't need to flush cache.  [See Tsuna's blog](http://blog.tsunanet.net/2010/11/how-long-does-it-take-to-make-context.html).  Cache pollution between threads will be minimized, since they can share the program cache, are performing the same task, and are sharing the same copy of the code.  We're talking savings on the order of 100's of nanoseconds to several microseconds per switch.  If that's small potatoes for you, then read on...

Depending on the design, the I/O data path may be shorter for one process.

The startup and warmup time for a thread is generally much shorter.  The OS doesn't have to start a process, Java doesn't have to start another JVM, classloading is only done once, JIT-compilation is only done once, and HotSpot optimizations are done once, and sooner.

Comment: Context-switching between jobs in the same process is not significantly cheaper than switching between processes -- the vast majority of the cost of a context switch on a modern CPU comes from blowing out the code and data caches, which is the same either way. If a design has so many context switches that context switch performance matters, the design is very badly broken.

Comment: *"it's a lot cheaper to switch between threads than between processes"* - please could you provide some references/benchmarks to back this up. Thanks.

Comment: Another reason is that Java provides you with thread-pool, executor -service and task-queue code to handle this case easilly.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: context switch between OS processes will erase the VM caches in the processor, which will result in many extra memory accesses to the page tables.  This does not happen in a context switch between threads, as the address space does not change.  But if you can live with that, I like the OS process approach, because worker processes are more robust, as a memory or other resource leak in one process will not affect the others.

Answer (score 18):

Well usually, when discussing multi processing (/w one thread per process) versus multi threading in the same process, while the theoretical overhead is bigger in the first case than in the latter (and thus multi processing is theoretically slower than multi threading), in reality on most modern OSs this is not such a big issue. However when discussing it in the Java context, starting a new process is a lot more costly then starting a new thread. Starting a new process means starting up a new instance of the JVM which is very costly especially in terms of memory. I recommend that you start multiple threads in the same JVM.

Moreover, if you say inter-thread communication is not an issue, you can use Java's [Executor Service](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5,0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) to get a fixed thread pool of size 2x(number of available CPUs). The number of available CPU's can be autodetected at runtime via Java's Runtime class. This way you get a quick simple multithreading going without any boiler plate code.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, if you do this with large scale taks using multiple jvm process is way faster than one jvm with multple threads. At least we never got one jvm runnning as fast as multple jvms.

We do some calculations where each task uses around 2-3GB ram and does some heavy number crunching. If we spawn 30 jvm's and run 30 task they perform around 15-20% better than spawning 30 threads in one jvm. We tried tuning the gc and the various memory sections and never catched up to the first variant.

We did this on various machines 14 tasks on a 16 core server, 34 tasks on a 36 core server etc. Multithreading in java always performed worde than multiple jvm processes.

It may not make any difference on simple tasks but on heavy calculations it seems jvm performce bad on threads.