# Do multiple processes(pods in this case) increase the rate of processing?

Tags: docker, process, kubernetes, cpu

Assume a VM with 4 cores. I have a docker image which has a web application that provides some REST services. I am using K8S to deploy this application on that VM. So, is there any difference if I use a single pod on the single VM  vs  mutiple pods on the same host, in terms of performance.

For people who don't know K8S, assume we have some application that provides some REST services. Is there any advantage of using multiple instances of such application in terms of a performance increase like increased rate of serving requests ?

Comment: Horizontal scaling works sometimes, depending on what your actual bottleneck is and what you’re trying to optimize for.  It’s impossible to say generically “yes more X will be faster”, though.  Do you have a more specific question or a specific workload you’re working with?

Comment: Consider reading answers on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7903503/java-performance-processes-vs-threads

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I think the performance had better to run `multiple pods` on the same host. I don't know what `web server` you use, but the requests are processed by `limited cpu time`, though it has `multiple processes` or `threads` for work. Additionally it's more efficient to utilize cpu time during `network I/O waiting` in using multiple processes. In order to improve the `throughput`, you should increase the processes or instances to work horizontally, because the `response time` is getting slower as time past.